# Ignore errors in Observable and Continue

Tags: rxjs

How to do some action if error happen in stream, but continue to receive new items? For example, I need to  just logging error, but continue to receive data from server. I tried a lot of solutions from stackoverflow, but stream always behave like closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite easy:

```
const frontendMessagesStream = new Subject<FrontendMessage>()
frontendMessagesStream
    .pipe(
        tap(console.log),
        map(someThrow),
        tap(console.log),
        catchError((err, o) => o), // the second parameter will be your observable. It replaces your stream.
    )
    .subscribe()
```

Comment: In my case it ends up with, calling the same stream again and again

Comment: Depending on the type of observable this can have undesired side effects. In the case of a hot observable, a subject, this may work. In the case of a cold observable this won't work as intended as it will resubscribe to the observable.